# how to optimise this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table `sales` with columns `ID,paymentType,price` in SQL Server 2005.

```
create table sales(id int IDENTITY(1,1),
                   paymentType varchar(2), 
                   price decimal(10,2) default(0)
                  )
```

Is there a way to do this in one query ?

```
SELECT SUM(price) as TE 
FROM sales 
WHERE paymentType = 'E' 

SELECT SUM(price) as TC 
FROM sales 
WHERE paymentType = 'C'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` and `CASE()` to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN paymentType = 'E' THEN price ELSE 0 END) TE,
        SUM(CASE WHEN paymentType = 'C' THEN price ELSE 0 END) TC
FROM    TableName
WHERE   paymentType IN ('E','C')
```

There `WHERE` is needed to filter on specific payments and not to scan the whole table. You also need to add index on column `paymentType` to improve the performance more.

Comment: thanks a lot , I have a question,if I use Where paymentType = 'E' it will scan ALL table ?

Comment: if you have indexes define, then no. otherwise yes.

Comment: the output of this query query will be a two-column result: `TE` and `TC`

Answer (score 6):

You can use GROUP BY to group your values by paymentType and get two records of 'E' and 'C' with sums

```
SELECT paymentType,SUM(price) 
FROM sales 
WHERE paymentType = 'E' or paymentType = 'C'
GROUP BY paymentType
```